# control the kinect

Tags: kinect

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all!

Is it possible to control the kinect motor (falling gradient from the kinect) by ROS?

Thank you for help!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/55116/control-the-kinect/) by [JaRu](https://answers.ros.org/users/3620/jaru/) on ROS Answers with karma: 153 on 2013-02-13

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I use the ROS package "kinect_aux" to control the motor and the LED.
And also to get the IMU data.

---

Originally posted by [MichaelKorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/905/michaelkorn/) with karma: 1480 on 2013-02-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 5

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [georgebrindeiro](https://answers.ros.org/users/2573/georgebrindeiro/) on 2013-02-13**:
Nice tip, thanks!

**Comment by [JaRu](https://answers.ros.org/users/3620/jaru/) on 2013-02-13**:
Thanks, how can I install this package? I use ROS electric and only found it for diamondback.

**Comment by [JaRu](https://answers.ros.org/users/3620/jaru/) on 2013-02-13**:
I install the package for ROS diamondback, it works.

**Comment by [georgebrindeiro](https://answers.ros.org/users/2573/georgebrindeiro/) on 2013-02-13**:
If the answer was good enough for your needs, please mark this answer as correct by clicking the checkmark under the voting buttons.

**Comment by [Jon Stephan](https://answers.ros.org/users/2281/jon-stephan/) on 2013-02-20**:
FYI - I found the source at git://github.com/ros-pkg-git/kinect.git, and the kinect_aux part still compiled.  I don't know how to install the old package.

**Comment by [MichaelKorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/905/michaelkorn/) on 2013-02-20**:
What do you mean with "install"?

**Comment by [Jon Stephan](https://answers.ros.org/users/2281/jon-stephan/) on 2013-02-21**:
I meant I don't know how to install it with apt-get.  I suppose I'd have to add the old diamondback repository and I guess I could look that up.  The point of my comment was actually to post the link to the source repository, which wasn't on the wiki.

**Comment by [MichaelKorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/905/michaelkorn/) on 2013-02-21**:
As far as I know there is no repository with kinect_aux for fuerte or groovy. The old diamondback repository will not work, the package muss be compiled for/with fuerte.

**Comment by [Jon Stephan](https://answers.ros.org/users/2281/jon-stephan/) on 2013-02-21**:
Ah.  Ok.  I added a link to the git repo on the wiki page.